# Trouble with simple CDI Injection... "Passivation" related error when using @Inject in SessionScoped Controller bean

Tags: java, model-view-controller, cdi, jsf-2.2

Okay— I am assuming I am making a very obvious mistake here— but I can’t seem to find my answer through the several Google/SO searches I have done. My background with Java programming is heavily JSF based, and at work I only have experience using Faces to manage my beans (using the `@Managed` annotation). However, I am working on a personal project in which I am trying to use CDI for the first time. I am having trouble injecting a Service bean into a `SessionScoped` controller bean… It’s odd because I inject the same service bean into a different `RequestScoped` bean no problem… I don’t see what I am missing. I have the `SessionScoped` bean implementing `Serializable`, yet I am still getting the following error when I try to deploy, **ONLY** once I have added an `@Inject` variable to the bean (without which the bean will be pretty useless…): `Caused by: org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansConfigurationException: Passivation capable beans must satisfy passivation capable dependencies.` Here’s a bit of my service and controller beans code:

**UserService.java**

```
import ds.nekotoba.model.User;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.Transactional;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashingPasswordService;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Hash;

@Named
@Transactional//Makes all methods in bean transactional
public class UserService {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public User findById(Long id) {
        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }

    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUsername", User.class)
                .setParameter("username", username)
                .getSingleResult();
    }

    public User find(String username, String password) {
        List<User> found = em.createNamedQuery("User.find", User.class)
                .setParameter("username", username)
                .setParameter("password", password)
                .getResultList();
        return found.isEmpty() ? null : found.get(0);
    }

    @Produces
    @Named("users")
    @RequestScoped
    public List<User> list() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("User.list", User.class).getResultList();
    }

    public Long create(User user) {
        ….
    }

    public void update(User user){
        em.merge(user);
    }

    public void delete(User user){
        em.remove(em.contains(user) ? user : em.merge(user));
    }
}
```

**LoginController.java** Note: The `@Inject` calls in this bean work no problem!

```
import ds.nekotoba.model.User;
import ds.nekotoba.service.UserService;
import ds.nekotoba.util.Globals;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.web.util.SavedRequest;
import org.apache.shiro.web.util.WebUtils;
import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;
import org.omnifaces.util.Messages;

@Named(value="login")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController {

    public LoginController() {
    }

    @Inject ProfileController profile;
    @Inject UserService userService;

    //Variables
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean remember;

    //<editor-fold desc="Getters/Setters">
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isRemember() {
        return remember;
    }

    public void setRemember(boolean remember) {
        this.remember = remember;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    public void submit() throws IOException {
        try {//Attempt login
            SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password, remember));
        } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("不明なユーザ、また試してみてください。");
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }

        //If successful, set User in ProfileController, get full user info 
        if(SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()){
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);
            profile.setUserInfo(user);
            //profile.refreshUserInfo(); //COMMENTED OUT DUE TO ERROR INJECTED IN ProfileController.java
        }

        //Redirect to intended page
        SavedRequest savedRequest = WebUtils.getAndClearSavedRequest(Faces.getRequest());
        Faces.redirect(savedRequest != null ? savedRequest.getRequestUrl() : Globals.HOME_URL);
    }

}
```

**ProfileController.java** (The error mentioned above manifests once I use any `@Inject` calls in this bean…)

```
import ds.nekotoba.model.User;
import ds.nekotoba.service.UserService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value="profile")
@SessionScoped
public class ProfileController implements Serializable {

    @Inject UserService userService;//CAUSES ERROR MENTIONED ABOVE

    //Variables
    private User userInfo;


    public ProfileController() {
    }

    public void refreshUserInfo() {
        userInfo = userService.findByUsername(userInfo.getUsername());
    }

    //<editor-fold desc="Getters/Setters">
    public User getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void setUserInfo(User userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }
    //</editor-fold>
}
```

Like I said, I am a new-comer to CDI injection, so I am sure I am missing something obvious… I just can’t figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Other Project Info:**
JSF 2.2
JPA 2.0
TomEE 1.7.1
OmniFaces 1.8.1
Apache Shiro 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT
Apache DeltaSpike (could this be a conflicting point?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo implements Serializable` is necessary but not sufficient for `Foo` to be serializable. All members of `Foo` also have to be serializable.

In your case, `ProfileController` is serializable, but its `UserService` member is not.

Comment: Okay... So-- what are my options? Do I simply implement Serializable on the UserService too? I don't want to change the scope of it. I'll have to try this when I get home. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for this catch, it was in fact my problem. I'm realizing now that the template class we use in projects at work all implement `Serializable` as a rule-- so I've never run into this particular exception before. Thanks again!

Comment: As stated in my previous comment-- the general trend at my work is to simply implement `Serializable` on all Controller/Service/Model beans... is this a common/good practice to avoid unexpected and seemingly random errors like what I got above when injected/resolving to an instance of a bean? Is there any unnecessary overhead introduced by this approach? Or is this industry standard?

Comment: IMO your UserService should be AppScoped.
It has no members and currently a new instance will be created for each @Inject because the default CDI scope is Dependent.
As you inject it into your ProfileController, the UserService would be serialized into the session if you enabled failover/clustering.

Comment: @tandraschko Hmmm... I do see what you are saying about the default `Dependent` scope inadvertently inheriting the parent bean's scope on `@Inject`, but do I really want/need it to be `ApplicationScoped`?. Wouldn't setting it to `RequestScoped` avoid the issue you describe, and ensure the `UserService` never has retained values to erroneously serve to another injection point in the application? Further more, wouldn't this save some on memory usage caused by serialization of an `ApplicationScoped` service bean? Thanks for you input thus far!